# Outlook Reply o Reply All desde C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, outlook

Tengo una app donde ya puedo enviar un correo mediante SMTP.
Ahora cuando me responder ese correo obtengo la ID de la conversación (ConversationID) y lo guardo en la base de datos.

Que es lo que intento...Quisiera hacer Reply o Reply All desde mi app a ese correo usando el ID de la conversación y es aquí donde estoy atorado.
Como puedo responder usando el ID que guarde del correo?

No tengo nada de código de esa parte, solamente de como le envió.

Saludos.

Comment: Puedes añadir el codigo de como lo envias, asi podremos ayudarte mas facil